# Change font of selected line in disassembly view in WinDbg

Tags: customization, windbg

Does anybody know how to change font in one particular line in disassembly view of WinDbg?

It looks like this:
[image]

If to scroll it up or down, still the selected line is outstanding from every other line. However if to load workspace explicitly via "File -> Open workspace..." (Ctrl + W) then the line is the same as any others.

Why does it happen?

Comment: AFAIK there's only one place to change the font (View/Font...) and it's not possible for each different color (View/Options...) so that seems more like a bug to me.

Comment: Why do you need this? What is the scenario you want to accomplish?

Comment: @seva titov Actually nothing special, just looking at the code and seeing all the same lines, not the one odd and others the same.

Comment: @Thomas Weller Yup, it's not possible to set different font sizes through menu so it looks strange, to me it also seems to be a bug.